# ¿Como convertir números a letras en Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tengo un reporte hecho con iReport, donde me muestra el total de una suma de valores. Quiero convertir ese valor numérico a letras. ¿Como puede realizar dicha conversión? 
Por ejemplo la suma da como resultado 50, al momento de imprimir quiero que en el reporte aparezca "cincuenta"

Comment: a que te refieres con *convertir ese valor numérico a letras* exactamente? `10` a `diez` o `int 10` a `String "10"`, que has intentado hasta ahora? algun error? como recoges el total de la suma?

Comment: @Jordi con convertir a valor numérico a letras, me refiero a que si tengo por ejemplo 50, puede imprimir en el reporte "cincuenta" . El total de la suma lo se hace al configurar el campo como auto suma de toda la columna.

Answer (score 1):

Hola hace unos días me encontre con el mismo problema, y por alguna página me aparecio este código.

```
final private static String[] units = { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
        "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen",
        "Nineteen" };
final private static String[] tens = { "", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty",
        "Ninety" };

public String convert(Integer i) {
    //
    if (i < 20)
        return units[i];
    if (i < 100)
        return tens[i / 10] + ((i % 10 > 0) ? " " + convert(i % 10) : "");
    if (i < 1000)
        return units[i / 100] + " Hundred" + ((i % 100 > 0) ? " and " + convert(i % 100) : "");
    if (i < 1000000)
        return convert(i / 1000) + " Thousand " + ((i % 1000 > 0) ? " " + convert(i % 1000) : "");
    return convert(i / 1000000) + " Million " + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? " " + convert(i % 1000000) : "");
}
```

Tu lo llamarias así:

```
 int cualquierNumero = 1234;
    System.out.println(convert(cualquierNumero));
```

espero te sirva.

Answer (score -1):

En el editor del *expresion value* de cada campo puedes escribir cosas como

```
String.valueOf($F{MI_CAMPO_NUMERICO})
Integer.valueOf($F{MI_CAMPO_LITERAL})
```

Siempre que tengas configurado que se trata de contenido tipo Java (normalmente es la opción por defecto)